# Which UML colors should this example be represented by?

Tags: uml, stereotypes, color

See UML colors [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_colors).

Here is the example, I have following entity classes:

```
User(name)

MailBox(owner: User, label)

Mail(from: User, to: User, subject, body, composeTime)

MailCopy(type, from: User, to: User, subject, body)

MailDelivery(mailCopy, mailBox)
```

Use case: Every users have three mailboxes by default: `MailBox(*, draft)`, `MailBox(*, received)` and `MailBox(*, sent)`. `User(alice)` composed a new `Mail(alice, bob, hello, world)`, and clicked the "send" button. A new `MailCopy(SOURCE, alice, bob, hello, world)` is created and delivered to the `MailBox(alice, sent)`, and another copy `MailCopy(DEST, alice, bob, hello, world)` is created and delivered to the `MailBox(bob, received)`.

I want to know how to classify these entities according to the UML colors archetype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User can be green or yellow depending on how you look at it (if the User is a system role it's yellow, if it's User as in a person, it's Green).

Mailbox is green...but the owner should be extracted out as a yellow role (which tells me mailbox **should** be pink -- roles go from a green to a pink...rarely from green to green). Technically the Mailbox is an Account which is definitely a Pink Moment Interval...let's call it an E-Mail Account (the moment is when the account was open so you might want to record that).

Mail is green but it has two pinks associated with it. Sent Mail, and Delivered Mail.

On both Mail Events, the Sender (or From) is yellow, and the Recipient (or To) is also yellow.

Looking closer at your specs, I'm not sure MailCopy is necessary. You have the Mail Object itself, after it's created it should be uneditable so anyone who needs it just points to the same copy.

What you're calling Mailbox, I would call folder which would be green. I would reference the mail to the folder using a pink folder assignment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for the great advice. So MailAccount should be pink, and MailFolder should be green, right? Everything in the system could have a created-time, then how do I recognize whose created-time should be a moment-interval?

Comment: And, should I make MailOwner, MailSender, MailRecipient as separate entities? It feels like unnecessary, though.

Comment: Sometimes entities can be implied so you don't HAVE to create the separate MailOwner, MailSender, MailRecipient roles. Just be aware that they exist and be ready to extract them when the application needs them. MailFolder is green...the creation of the mailfolder is pink (it could be implied as well). Sometimes following the rules explicitly makes a verbose domain but knowing where you can imply the entities versus needing to extract them is as important as knowing the rules.

Comment: Mail should be pink, if consider it as an effort result by the user, and it implied the yellow MailFrom and MailTo, right?

Comment: @Mike: Take `Product` as another example, a `Product` may have created-date and expire-date, so should it be pink?

Comment: Product as a single, physical, tangible item is green. Product as a description is blue. The difference is subtle. A batch of milk produced on 5/10/2011 with batch number 429 is green. Stackexchange Milk is blue.

Comment: An action is what we look at a pink. So for a dairy farm control application you might have MilkBatchCreation as a pink object. Or if you were controlling a CPU factory you would have i7Q750 as a blue and CPU with id 12345 as green (with the i7Q750 blue descriptor attached), and CpuCertification as a Pink (having a certified date). BTW in case you don't have it, Java Modeling in Color with UML is a great reference for all of this http://www.amazon.com/Java-Modeling-Color-UML-Enterprise/dp/013011510X